# Grouping items in assoc. array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array with the following contents:

```
Array
(
    [L_TIMESTAMP0] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a57%3a38Z
    [L_TIMESTAMP1] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a45%3a23Z
    [L_TIMESTAMP2] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a35%3a54Z
    [L_TIMEZONE0] => GMT
    [L_TIMEZONE1] => GMT
    [L_TIMEZONE2] => GMT
    [L_STATUS0] => Completed
    [L_STATUS1] => Completed
    [L_STATUS2] => Completed
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2011%2d10%2d16T17%3a58%3a39Z
)
```

What I want to do is to 'group' all instances of L_TIMESTAMP0, L_TIMEZONE0 and L_STATUS0 (and L_TIMESTAMP1, L_TIMEZONE1, L_STATUS1) into their own array, or as part of a multidimensional array. But I simply can't seem to figure out how I would go about accomplishing this.

The expected results would be:

```
Array
    (
        [L_TIMESTAMP0] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a57%3a38Z
        [L_TIMEZONE0] => GMT
        [L_STATUS0] => Completed
    )

Array
    (
        [L_TIMESTAMP1] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a45%3a23Z
        [L_TIMEZONE1] => GMT
        [L_STATUS1] => Completed
    )
```

I figured this would be simple with a simple for-loop, but that doesn't give me the results I'm looking for.

Any ideas?
It's likely something very obvious, but I've spent the last few days with this and I can't figure it out (although that probably says more about my skills than the problem)

edit:
To add; I don't need the exact code for my particular question, but any pointers as to what direction I should look into would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: Could you give the expected result?

Comment: Hi Felix, I don't have any relevant code, since I don't know what I should be trying.

Comment: Is there a limit of elements which starts with the same key? Like max. 3 timezones, etc.

Comment: @xdazz: Expected result added.

Comment: @FelixKling 100 keys max. E.g. L_TIMESTAMP0-99. No limit on the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$groupRegex = '/([0-9]+)$/';
$multiArray = array();
$assocArray = array (
    "L_TIMESTAMP0" => "2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a57%3a38Z",
    "L_TIMESTAMP1" => "2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a45%3a23Z",
    "L_TIMESTAMP2" => "2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a35%3a54Z",
    "L_TIMEZONE0" => "GMT",
    "L_TIMEZONE1" => "GMT",
    "L_TIMEZONE2" => "GMT",
    "L_STATUS0" => "Completed",
    "L_STATUS1" => "Completed",
    "L_STATUS2" => "Completed",
    "TIMESTAMP" => "2011%2d10%2d16T17%3a58%3a39Z"
);

foreach( $assocArray as $key => $value ) {
preg_match( $groupRegex, $key, $group );

    if( !isset($group[1]) ){
    continue;
    }

$group = intval( $group[1] );
    if( is_array( $multiArray[$group] ) ) {
    $multiArray[$group][$key] = $value;
    }
    else {
    $multiArray[$group] = array( $key => $value );
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $multiArray);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [L_TIMESTAMP0] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a57%3a38Z
        [L_TIMEZONE0] => GMT
        [L_STATUS0] => Completed
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [L_TIMESTAMP1] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a45%3a23Z
        [L_TIMEZONE1] => GMT
        [L_STATUS1] => Completed
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [L_TIMESTAMP2] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a35%3a54Z
        [L_TIMEZONE2] => GMT
        [L_STATUS2] => Completed
    )

)
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome. Thanks! I suspected I would have to start preg_match'ing, but wasn't sure of how I would approach it. That helps a bunch.

Comment: Note that while it matches your expected result, it would be better if the resulting multidimensional array didn't retain the numbering in the string keys since the numbering would be redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
$restructuring = true;
$count = 0;
$new_array = array();
while($restructuring)
{
  $restructuring = false;
  foreach($original_array as $oa)
  {
    if(!array_key_exists($count, $new_array) && array_key_exists('L_TIMESTAMP'.$count, $original_array))
    {
      $new_element = array();
      foreach(array('TIMESTAMP', 'TIMEZONE', 'STATUS') as $e)
      if(!empty($original_array['L_'.$e.$count])) $new_element[$e.$count] = $original_array['L_'.$e.$count];
      $new_array[] = $new_element;
      $count++;
      $restructuring = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Given $original_array as defined in the question, the $new_array will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP0] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a57%3a38Z
            [TIMEZONE0] => GMT
            [STATUS0] => Completed
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP1] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a45%3a23Z
            [TIMEZONE1] => GMT
            [STATUS1] => Completed
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP2] => 2011%2d10%2d16T16%3a35%3a54Z
            [TIMEZONE2] => GMT
            [STATUS2] => Completed
        )

)
```

Comment: I originally left out the numbers in the keys for the sub elements, since they are redundant, but I saw the adjustment you made to the question where you put the numbers in the keys, so I added them in.